# JAVASCRIPT: pass json key's name as parameter, and use the parameter to get the value

Tags: javascript, json, key

In javascript, is there a way to treat a JSON keyname as a variable?

For instance, below I want to perform (any set of actions) on the value of a different key in JSON each time, by telling it which json key to get by feeding the keyname to the function as a parameter.

The basic idea here is:  Make a function to do (x) no matter what JSON it's given. I just need to tell it what key I want.

```
var myObj = {name: "John", age: 31}; // dataset #1
var myObj2 = {month: "January", day: 20}; //dataset #2

function myFunction(jsonName, variableKeyName) {   

  var variableKeyValue = jsonName + "." + variableKeyName;  //wrong way to do this, apparently.
 
  console.log(variableKeyValue); 
}

myFunction("myObj", "name"); //want this to log "John", not the string "myObj.name".
myFunction("myObj2", "day"); //want this to log "20", not the string "myObj2.day".
```

Is this possible?  How do get the function to assign the VALUE of the string I'm building with the parameter, rather than just the string as "jsonNameX.variableKeyNameX"?

Answer (score 2):

```
const myObj = {name: "John", age: 31}; // dataset #1
const myObj2 = {month: "January", day: 20}; //dataset #2

function myFunction(json, variableKeyName) {   
  const variableKeyValue = json[variableKeyName]; 
  console.log(variableKeyValue); 
}

myFunction(myObj, "name"); // this log "John"
myFunction(myObj2, "day"); // this log 20
```

or you can access to global context using "this" keyword and variable name (instead variable identifier == reference)

```
const myObj = {name: "John", age: 31}; // dataset #1
const myObj2 = {month: "January", day: 20}; //dataset #2

function myFunction(jsonName, variableKeyName) {   
  const variableKeyValue = this[jsonName][variableKeyName]; 
  console.log(variableKeyValue); 
}

myFunction("myObj", "name"); // this log "John"
myFunction("myObj2", "day"); // this log 20
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco Mazzone!  this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. You can get the JSON value like this:

```
jsonName.variableKeyName;
```

but you can also get it like this:

```
jsonName["variableKeyName"];
```

(https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)

So you can change your code in this way:

```js
var myObj = {name: "John", age: 31}; // dataset #1
var myObj2 = {month: "January", day: 20}; //dataset #2

function myFunction(jsonName, variableKeyName) {  
  var variableKeyValue = jsonName[variableKeyName];
  console.log(variableKeyValue ); 
}

myFunction(myObj, "name"); //this prints "John"
myFunction(myObj2, "day"); //this prints "20"
```

Comment: Please tell me if you want something different

Comment: OMG thank you, @Nick Pantelidis! I don't know why my brain just didn't make that leap but this this is exactly what I needed.  I don't even know why I was trying to concatenate the variables together as a string in the first place.   Thanks!